# Issue with Performance of Rust Code vs Go

Tags: performance, rust

I realise this isn't a typical question here, but I'd really appreciate if someone would look through this code and tell me why it's so slow (the dictionary used is about 1400 words) and my Go code runs this is like 5 mins, but my Rust code takes like 100 mins.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

#[allow(dead_code)]

struct Key {
    a: [char; 25],
    b: [char; 25],
    c: [char; 25],
    d: [char; 25],
}

struct Coords {
    row: i32,
    column: i32,
}

fn letters() -> [char; 25] {
    let l: [char; 25] = [
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    ];
    l
}

fn format_text(original: String) -> String {
    let mut result: String = "".to_string();
    for i in 0..original.len() {
        if original.as_bytes()[i] >= 65 && original.as_bytes()[i] <= 90 {
            result.push(original.as_bytes()[i] as char)
        }
    }
    result
}

fn scan_tetragrams() -> HashMap<String, i32> {
    let mut tg: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let file = File::open("../tetragrams.txt").expect("Failed to load tetragram file");
    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let ln: &str = &line.unwrap_or(String::from("Invalid line"));
        let fields: Vec<&str> = ln.split(", ").collect();
        let n: Result<i32, _> = fields[1].parse();
        let num: i32 = match n {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => panic!("Failed to convert tetragram frequence to i32"),
        };
        tg.insert(fields[0].to_string(), num);
    }
    tg
}

fn gen_reference(n: usize) -> String {
    let r: Vec<u8> = format_text(read("../referenceText.txt"))
        .as_bytes()
        .to_vec();
    let mut ref_text: String = String::from("");
    for i in 0..n {
        ref_text = format!("{}{}", ref_text, String::from(r[i] as char));
    }
    ref_text
}

fn scan_dict() -> Vec<String> {
    let words: Vec<String> = read("../challenge_word_list.txt")
        .split(" ")
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
        .iter()
        .map(|&s| s.into())
        .collect(); //this was painful lmao
    words[..words.len() - 1].to_vec() //last element is a newline character otherwise
}

fn read(path: &str) -> String {
    let f: Result<String, std::io::Error> = fs::read_to_string(path);
    match f {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(_) => panic!("Couldn't find file"),
    }
}

fn score(text: &String, tetragrams: &HashMap<String, i32>) -> i32 {
    let bytes = text.as_bytes();
    let mut total: i32 = 0;
    for i in 0..text.len() - 3 {
        let v: Vec<u8> = (bytes[i..i + 4]).to_vec();
        let s: Result<String, _> = String::from_utf8(v);
        let slice = match s {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(_) => panic!("Failed to parse window in text"),
        };
        if tetragrams.contains_key(&slice) {
            total += tetragrams[&slice];
        }
    }
    total
}

fn fill_grid(keyword: &mut String) -> [char; 25] {
    let mut seen: HashSet<char> = HashSet::new();
    keyword.retain(|c| {
        let s = seen.contains(&c);
        seen.insert(c);
        !s
    }); //remove duplicate letters from keyword

    let last_idx = letters()
        .iter()
        .position(|&x| x == keyword.chars().last().unwrap())
        .unwrap(); //continues filling up grid with next letter after last letter in keyword
    let mut grid: Vec<char> = keyword
        .as_bytes()
        .to_vec()
        .iter()
        .map(|x| *x as char)
        .collect(); //also painful
    for i in last_idx..last_idx + 25 {
        let idx = i % 25;
        if !seen.contains(&letters()[idx]) {
            seen.insert(letters()[idx]);
            grid.push(letters()[idx]);
        }
    }
    let t: Result<[char; 25], _> = grid.try_into();
    match t {
        Ok(arr) => arr,
        Err(_) => panic!("Failed to fill grid"),
    }
}

fn coordinates(grid_index: i32) -> Coords {
    let row: i32 = grid_index / 5;
    let column: i32 = grid_index - row * 5;
    Coords { row, column }
}

fn grid_index(row: i32, column: i32) -> i32 {
    row * 5 + column
}

fn decipher(text: &String, k: Key) -> Option<String> {
    let mut deciphered: String = String::from("");
    let bytes = text.as_bytes();
    for i in (0..text.len() - 1).step_by(2) {
        let v: Vec<u8> = (bytes[i..i + 2]).to_vec();
        let i1: usize = k.b.iter().position(|&x| x == v[0] as char)?;
        let i2: usize = k.c.iter().position(|&x| x == v[1] as char)?;
        let coords1: Coords = coordinates(i1.try_into().ok()?);
        let coords2: Coords = coordinates(i2.try_into().ok()?);

        let d_i1: usize = grid_index(coords1.row, coords2.column)
            .try_into()
            .expect("Failed to get grid index 1"); //coords of deciphered letters
        let d_i2: usize = grid_index(coords2.row, coords1.column)
            .try_into()
            .expect("Failed to get grid index 2");

        let letter1: String = String::from(k.a[d_i1]);
        let letter2: String = String::from(k.d[d_i2]);
        deciphered = format!("{}{}{}", deciphered, letter1, letter2);
    }
    Some(deciphered)
}

fn dictionary_attack(ciphertext: &String) {
    let dict = scan_dict();
    let tetragrams = scan_tetragrams();
    let ref_score = score(&gen_reference(ciphertext.clone().len()), &tetragrams);
    let mut count: i32 = 0;
    for word in &dict {
        println!("{}", count);
        count += 1;
        if word.contains("J") || word.len() == 1 {
            continue;
        }
        for word2 in &dict {
            if word2.contains("J") || word2.len() == 1 {
                continue;
            }
            let k: Key = Key {
                a: letters(),
                b: fill_grid(&mut word.to_string()),
                c: fill_grid(&mut word2.to_string()),
                d: letters(),
            };
            let p = decipher(&ciphertext, k).unwrap();
            if score(&p, &tetragrams) * 10 >= ref_score * 8 {
                println!("{}", p)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let original = read("src/ciphertext.txt");
    let ciphertext: String = format_text(original);
    dictionary_attack(&ciphertext)
}
```

I initially had quite a few .clone()s in the dictionary_attack function, but I removed these. I then replaced some .unwrap()s with the ? operator and .expect() because I thought that might have been what was causing the problem, but it's still way slower than I expected.

Comment: Obligatory question: are you running in `--release` mode?

Comment: What does the program do? Can you give us some context?

Comment: Well, I don't know Swift, so I probably shouldn't say anything but your `format_text()` function, for example, looks very clunky: Why do you feel the need to convert back and forth from characters to bytes? That could be very expensive depending on Swift's sophistication when optimizing.

Comment: This really belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TimRoberts Not with the current lack of description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a quick look at your code and:

- you keep converting between `String` and `Vec<u8>`

  - `String` => `Vec<u8>` can be very fast if you use `into()` instead of copying;
  - `Vec<u8>` => `String` requires scanning the entire array to check that it's valid UTF-8, so it's always slow;
  - I suggest keeping a single representation through the algorithm;
- I see you allocating a `String` for every char, you don't need it and it's going to be fairly slow;
- `letters` should be a `const` instead of a function;
- you could use `entry` to avoid your double lookup in `HashSet`;
- `keyword.chars().last()` is slow because it's Unicode;
- in your definition of `grid`, you're converting twice to a vector, once would be sufficient;
- etc.

Sadly, I don't have time for a full review, but there are many inefficiencies that can be fixed.

Also, may I suggest using clippy? It's pretty good at noticing some inefficiencies while you're still typing.

Comment: *"keyword.chars().last() is slow because it's Unicode;"* - it doesn't require iterating from the beginning if that's what you're implying. Utf-8 can be read in reverse just fine, that's why `chars()` is a double-ended iterator in the first place.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks so much for taking the time to go through my code.